# Scapy - sniffing 2 interfaces out of three

Tags: python, scapy, network-interface

I'm using Scapy 2.2.0 and Python 2.6 to sniff on Windows 7. I know that you can supply the `iface` parameter to the `sniff` function. for example:

```
sniff(count=5,iface = 'eth0', prn=lambda p:p.show())
```

If you don't supply this parameter, it sniffs in all interfaces. But is there a way to choose 2 out of 3 interfaces? something like this: (it doesn't work)

```
sniff(count=5, iface='eth0, eth14', prn=lambda p:p.show())
```

Comment: Not possible. The better idea is either to use threads or just sniff everything and ignore those from the unwanted interface.

Comment: How can I know the interface that the packet came from? then I can try filtering the ones that came from unwanted interfaces

Comment: I'm curious on this too, either only using 2 specific interfaces, or filtering which interface the packet came from. what solution did you end up using?

Comment: I used threading to do it and it worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use threads in python and sniff each interface in a different thread:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: I know I can do it.. I thought there is a way with scapy

Answer (score 5):

As of version 2.3.3, it's now possible to specify multiple interfaces using an array, like this example from [scapy/usage.rst](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/scapy/usage.rst):

```
   sniff(iface=["eth1","eth2"], prn=lambda x: x.sniffed_on+": "+x.summary())
```

Comment: This is the best answer as of today.